# TemplateDoesNotExist (about jfu)

Tags: python, django, jquery-file-upload

django-jfu is django jquery file uploader [(https://github.com/Alem/django-jfu)](https://github.com/Alem/django-jfu)

jfutags.py:

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.template import Library, Context, loader

register = Library()

@register.simple_tag( takes_context = True )
def jfu(
        context,
        template_name = 'jfu/upload_form.html',
        upload_handler_name = 'jfu_upload',
        *args, **kwargs
    ):
    """
    Displays a form for uploading files using jQuery File Upload.

    A user may use both a custom template or a custom upload-handling URL
    name by supplying values for template_name and upload_handler_name
    respectively.

    Any additionally supplied positional and keyword arguments are directly
    forwarded to the named custom upload-handling URL.
    """
    context.update( { 
        'JQ_OPEN'  : '{%',
        'JQ_CLOSE' : '%}',
        'upload_handler_url': reverse(
            upload_handler_name, args = args, kwargs = kwargs
        ),
    } )

    # Use the request context variable, injected
    # by django.core.context_processors.request,
    # to generate the CSRF token.
    context.update( csrf( context.get('request') ) )

    t = loader.get_template( template_name )

    return t.render( Context( context ) )
```

In my topic.html , I used its tags in this way and I want `topic.id` to be passed as an argument to the name='topic_pic_upload' URL.

```
{% load jfutags %}
{% jfu 'upload_form.html' 'topic_pic_upload' topic.id}
```

HOWEVER,it turns out

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /topic/122/
forum/topic.html
```

when it shows

```
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
C:\FairyBBS\account\templates\forum\topic.html (File does not exist)
C:\FairyBBS\forum\templates\forum\topic.html **(File exists)**
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of `{% jfu %}` template tag is a positional one which requires a context.

Maybe this will work?

`{% jfu request 'upload_form.html' 'topic_pic_upload' topic.id}`